# Using trigonometry to solve wheel problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

Problem: A wheel of radius 80cm is rolled along the ground. Through what angle in radians does the wheel turn when the wheel travels 13.6 metres?

I am unsure how to relate the distance travelled by the wheel into angles, and I'm not sure if I should begin solving the problem by seeing how many rotations that the wheel makes.

Comment: What is the circumference? Calculate it and make some proportions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to know the formula for the length of an arc of the circle given its degree measure:
$$L=2\pi r*\frac{\theta}{2\pi}$$
Where $r$ is the radius of the circle and $\theta$ is the angle measure of the arc. If your wheel rolls $13.6$ meters, then the length of the arc that has touched the ground is $13.6$ meters, or $1360$ centimeters. Since we also have that the radius is $80$ centimeters, we can substitute these into the formula:
$$1360=2\pi(80)*\frac{\theta}{2\pi}$$
And then we can solve for $\theta$:
$$1360=2\pi(80)*\frac{\theta}{2\pi}$$
$$1360=80\theta$$
$$\theta=17$$
So the answer is $17$ radians.

Answer (score 0):

To get radian measure, simply divide distance by radius.

$\displaystyle \frac{1360}{80}=\boxed{17}$ radians.

We have $2πr=$ full circle $=2π$ radians, so in a wheel of radius $r$, length of $r=1$ radian. That's where my reasoning comes from :)